# Randomly getting 'System.BadImageFormatException: Index not found' error in Web API after certain deployments to an Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, tfs, azure-web-app-service, octopus-deploy, octopus

I have an ASP.NET Web API application running on an Azure App Service which is, in turn, deployed via Octopus after a TFS build definition is completed.

After certain successful deployments (no errors happen nor in TFS nor in Octopus), the whole API stops working and all endpoints
respond with the following error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException
Index not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131124)
```

and the stack-trace looks like this:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Index not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131124)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TState](AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

The error is a bit mysterious because it doesn't seem to related to any particular set of changes in the source code or to any particular action. That's why it looks random.
At the moment, the only way I found to temporarily solve this is re-deploying the same Octopus' package. That restores the API.

However, it would be useful to understand what is really going on with the application when this error happens.
Which index is not being found? What does it mean getting a BadImageFormatException?

My suspicion is that something happens between Octopus and the Azure Web App.

Some additional information: 
Octopus version is v2018.6.2 
TFS version is 15.117.27414.0 
ASP.NET app targets .NET 4.5.2

Another information that I found is that after the first deployment in Octopus (the one that produces the failure), I saw the following line in the logs:

```
  17:16:00   Info     |       Successfully deployed to Azure. 0 objects added. 48 objects updated. 0 objects deleted.
```

Now, after the second deploy in Octopus (the re-deploy of the release that failed), one would expect to have "0 objects updated", but instead I got the following line:

```
18:48:57   Info     |       Successfully deployed to Azure. 0 objects added. 3 objects updated. 0 objects deleted.
```

Comment: Did this happens repeatedly (100% of the time since it started happening) ? Or even you got a failed deployments , in next time you could also get  successful deployments.

Comment: No, it doesn't happen repeatedly and even when I got a failed deployment, then next one could be successful. Let's say that 1 of 10 deployments has this failure. I tried enabling AppOffline in the deployment process to see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Enabling "AppOffline" didn't work.

Comment: Have your checked your network environment? Are you behind an VPN. 1 of 10 deployments has this failure, it's hard to troubleshoot this kind of issue. Some customers encountered  similar deploy failed issues which due to network or firewall related.

Comment: I'm not behind a VPN. The failure is impossible to reproduce taking into account the information I've collected so far, I totally agree that this is hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: I tried changing File Comparison to Checksum but also didn't work.

Comment: Also use some network filters to help with collecting information. And next time if the re-deployment failed again and be captured,  share the related fail logs . For now, could not offer your more help or give a right direction.

Comment: I have example logs of a failed deploy and the next re-deploy, but completely posting them here will expose all the app's keys. If you meant the exception captured by the application, I added the stack trace in the post.

Comment: Suggest you submit the issue to this 
 site https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/22/index.html (MS official support site) and share the log with shadowing your company/personal info, TFS PM and developer will kindly review it and give your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. Will do that.

Comment: Apparently, it is entirely related to Octopus. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/286261/randomly-getting-systembadimageformatexception-ind.html